# F1 score mismatch with publication

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, f1

I'm trying to reproduce the results of the baseline model from SEP28k paper but I struggle to get the details. Most strikingly, the F1 score for random prediction doesn't match the paper. Here are the statistics for the dataset classes (1k samples from the dataset as stated in the paper):

```
        Block Prolongation SoundRep WordRep Interjection
count    1000         1000     1000    1000         1000
unique      2            2        2       2            2
top     False        False    False   False        False
freq      829          834      879     834          636
```

and F1 score for randomly picking True/False for each label:

```
Block: 0.29 (0.14 in paper)
Prolongation: 0.25 (0.13 in paper)
SoundRep: 0.23 (0.095 in paper)
WordRep: 0.22 (0.043 in paper)
Interjection: 0.38 (0.14 in paper)
```

The evaluation code that I use is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

STUTTER_LABELS = ['Block', 'Prolongation', 'SoundRep', 'WordRep', 'Interjection']
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('SEP-28k_labels.csv')
    df = df[STUTTER_LABELS][df[STUTTER_LABELS].values.sum(axis=1) >= 2]
    df = df.sample(n=1000)
    print((df >= 2).describe())
    
    labels = torch.from_numpy(df.values >= 2).long()
    preds = torch.randint_like(labels, high=2)
    scores = [f1_score(labels[:, i], preds[:, i]) for i in range(5)]
    paper_scores = [0.137, 0.128, 0.095, 0.043, 0.136, 0.46]
    for name, score, paper_score in zip(STUTTER_LABELS, scores, paper_scores):
        print(f"{name}: {score:.2} ({paper_score:.2} in paper)")
```

and the csv is available on [SEP28k](https://github.com/apple/ml-stuttering-events-dataset) github.

I've tried both predicting on the dataset with stuttered speech only and with stuttered/fluent speech but the results for random classifier are much higher than the paper says. Maybe the reason for that is that I'm not sure what "soft prediction layer" means

```
Both models have two output
branches: a fluent/dysfluent prediction and a soft prediction
for each of the five event types
```

I've assumed that it predicts each class separately (e.x. sigmoid at the end of each of 5 output neurons).

So my question is:

1. Is the F1 score sensible with dataset statistics
2. Is soft prediction layer just a prediction for each class separately?